# Telerik - WPF - RadGridView Filter - How to set checkbox container to scroll?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

I'm still pretty green to WPF, and I'm trying to figure out how to work with a Telerik RadGrid for WPF.

The grid has a filter that automatically populates with checkboxes for every value in the field.  You can see the problem this creates below:

[image: Infinite Checkboxes]

Is there a way to make the component that contains the checkboxes scroll after a certain point?  Say, a max of 200 pixels or so?

I'm trying to maintain changes like this in a resource file.  I'm ok with XAML but not much of a C# programmer.  Here is what I currently have for the GridViewHeaderCell portion:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type telerik:GridViewHeaderCell}" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewHeaderCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewHeaderCell}">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_HeaderCellGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="GridViewHeaderCell" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF4B4B4B" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="1,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF292929" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6C6C6C"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="GridViewHeaderCell_Over" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0">
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFBA3" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFBDA" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD25A" Offset="0.43"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFEEBAE" Offset="0.42"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="GridViewHeaderCell_Selected" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF616161" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF989898" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB69A78"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFE17A" Offset="0.126"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD74E" Offset="0.996"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFDCAB" Offset="0.17"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFB062" Offset="0.57"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD18F" Offset="0.56"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFBA74"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                    <Path x:Name="PART_SortIndicator" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0L1,0 2,0 3,0 4,0 5,0 5,1 4,1 4,2 3,2 3,3 2,3 2,2 1,2 1,1 0,1 0,0z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="3" Margin="0,3,0,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="1"/>
                                <SkewTransform AngleY="0" AngleX="0"/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                    <telerik:FilteringDropDown x:Name="PART_DistinctFilterControl" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="False" Margin="0,0,8,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding FilteringUIVisibility}">
                        <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                            <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                        </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                    </telerik:FilteringDropDown>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}">
                        <Thumb.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Thumb.Style>
                    </Thumb>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}">
                        <Thumb.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Thumb.Style>
                    </Thumb>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="SortingState" Value="None"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewHeaderCell_Over">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewHeaderCell_Over">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortingState" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="PART_SortIndicator" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="PART_SortIndicator">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="GridViewHeaderCell_Selected" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortingState" Value="Descending">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="PART_SortIndicator" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="PART_SortIndicator">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="GridViewHeaderCell_Selected" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortingState" Value="None">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="PART_SortIndicator" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF5B5B5B" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF868686"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF4F4F4F" Offset="0.42"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0E0E0E" Offset="0.43"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF848484"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,3,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="DropMarkPen">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Pen Brush="White" Thickness="2"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

If you need additional information for the solution, please let me know!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just curious what version you are using and if there is any other styling in place within the application, as by default the dropdown has a max height of 250px and should handle scrolling.  This is the default view with a brand new project with the 2011.2.712.40 version:

[image: WPF Grid default filter]

If you can shed some more info on version number that would be a great next step, as the above is from the latest official release (not the new one tomorrow :D).  Because the filter control would be handled by this chunk of code:

```
                <telerik:FilteringDropDown x:Name="PART_DistinctFilterControl" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="False" Margin="0,0,8,0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding FilteringUIVisibility}"> 
                    <telerik:StyleManager.Theme> 
                        <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/> 
                    </telerik:StyleManager.Theme> 
                </telerik:FilteringDropDown>
```

but if that hasn't been modified/defined elsewhere then we need to dig deeper into what's causing the issue.

Comment: Hey Evan, thanks for the quick reply.  The project itself is using .NET 3.5 and the Telerik controls version is the 'RadControls for WPF Q1 2011'.  There are lots of resource files within the application, but I can't find anything that has a direct reference to the telerik:FilteringDropDown.  Is there a particular control that I should look for whose styling may affect that filter?

Comment: Hey Phillip, just tested with the Q1 (2011.1.315.35) and the style/out of the box still matches the above picture, so something definitely isn't being applied correctly.  Try searching in your code for PART_DistinctValuesList, that's the name for the item within the FilteringControl that holds distinct items.  It normally has a maxheight set at 242 for the content panel, so perhaps there is an implicit style that is overriding some settings?  If you can find some modification on PART_DistinctValuesList or implicit styling on ListBox or VirtualizingStackPanel that may be the culprit.

Comment: Ok, so I found the default template for this control on Telerik's site:  http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/changing-the-funnel-filter-icon.aspx.  I made sure that the x:Type and x:Key were both set to {x:Type telerik:FilteringDropDown}.  But it still seems to have no affect.  Wouldn't this normally make it default back to the original style?

Comment: Sorry, was sleeping. :D  If you remove the x:Key it should override the style for anywhere it exists that it doesn't specifically have a style key named.  Hopefully that fixes it, as I mentioned what you pasted above and what Q1/2011 looks like on my side are definitely different so you shouldn't even be seeing the filtering control look like that.  Worst case if it is anything you can zip and send over so I can review I'm reachable at hutnick (at) telerik.com.

Comment: I think I may have found the style culprit.  Thanks so much for your help!